# Making a makefile with 2 .cpps and a header file

Tags: c++, makefile, header-files

I have no idea how to make a makefile as I've only made them with a single cpp file. The files I need to be compiled are deck.cpp, main.cpp, and deck.h

How would I go about doing this in the most simple way possible?

Comment: 1) Did you do _any_ research on the topic? For example, reading the documentation of your make tool? 2) What is the point for writing a makefile for a single file? The true usefulness for them is for multi-file projects, so you don't need to recompile everything.

Comment: I did do some research but everything I found on the topic was really complicated and confusing. I made them for single files because my professor made us create them.

Comment: It was confusing... How? From your question - it looks like you didn't do **any** research, and just came here with "Please do it for me" kind of request. On a separate note: If it is your assignment, then the topic of makefiles should be covered by your course material, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

For simple problems, make is really good with implicit rules.  Your Makefile can be a one-liner:

```
deck: deck.o main.o deck.h
```

Note that this is not robust.  If you change deck.h, deck will be rebuilt, but it will use stale deck.o and main.o.  If that is a concern, you can add more dependencies and make it a 3-liner:

```
deck: main.o deck.o
deck.o: deck.h
main.o: deck.h
```

Comment: I get an error saying unknown type name 'class' and also recipe for target 'deck' failed

Comment: What commands are being executed?  It sounds like Make may be trying to compile your code as C rather than C++.